# What is the one charm wanting

Tags: grammar

Go visit the prairies in June, when for scores on scores of miles you wade knee-deep among tiger-lilies--what is the one charm wanting? --water--there is not a drop of water there! Were Niagara but a cataract of sand, would you travel your thousand miles to see it?

<1. Charm wanting - is this charm wanting or what is one charm you want?

2. Were Niagara - what is a subject for "were"?

Comment: I realized the second one is a if sentence

Comment: Please link to the source of this quote.

Answer (score 1):

"Wanting" in this sentence is an old-fashioned use of "want" meaning "to lack."  That a person would want water in the scene (according to the writer) is a bit of a pun.

The clause with Niagara is in the subjunctive; it could also be written, "If Niagara were but a cataract of sand."

Comment: Thank you. That means this meaning "to lack" isn't used any more? Or is there in modern English usage to refer that?

Comment: In modern English, "want" in the meaning "to lack" is archaic.